# Output elments of a two-dimension array

Tags: c++, arrays

I come across the problem:

I want to output elements of a two-dimension array,just like this

```
char cur[3][3] = {{'.','.','B'},{'B','W','.'},{'B','.','.'}};
for(int x=0;x<3;x++){
   for(int y=0;y<3;y++){
       cout<<cur[x][y];
   }
   cout<<endl;
}
```

This works fine. But I also come across the follwing method

```
for(int x=0;x<3;x++){
    cout<<cur[x]+1<<endl;
}
```

Why the method work well?  I can not understand the method. Can someone help me to explain it?  Thank you.

Comment: Those two methods dont do the same thing... one loops over 9 elements, the other only 3. Can you explain how the second "works well" since it doesnt do the same thing as the first?

Comment: The latter method can also output 9 elements.

Comment: Are you sure this works? I think cout << cur[0] << endl; will do the job instead.

Comment: @JerryChou that's pure luck. Nothing guarantees there's a null termination after the array

Answer (score 2):

I don't see how the second method could "work". It invokes undefined behavior because you are basically passing non-null-terminated char pointer.

When you call `cur[0][0]` it's the same as calling `*(*(cur + 0) + 0)` and so calling `cur[0] + 1` is the same as `*(cur + 0) + 1` which returns a pointer to the second element of the first subarray.

When you give a char pointer to cout, it will print each char it finds until it hits a 0, then it stops. Let's say that by any chance there is a zero at the end of each subarray, it will print the second element, then the third, then stop, and do that for each subarray.

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand the method with your help.

Comment: No problem, have fun and remember to be safe with pointers ;)

Answer (score 1):

In the second method, you only stop printing when you find a null mark `\0', otherwise, it will continuous printing whatever if founds in memory.

You can easily see this happening changing a bit your code:

```
char cur[3][3] = {{'.','.','B'},{'B','W','\0'},{'B','.','.'}};
for(int x=0;x<3;x++){
    cout<<cur[x]+1<<endl;
}
```

Now it prints:

```
.BBW
W
..
```

Comment: Online on [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1aad634183f54241)

Comment: what is the meaning of "+1" ?

Comment: That is what I am asking you. It was in your code. I have no idea, Indeed, you can just do `cout << cur[x] << endl` without the for loop and trigger this UB